# XtraScheduler not showing new appointment

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, devexpress

I'm using DexExpress's XtraScheduler Control, I've used created a custom form to create and edit appointment. It is created successfully and on reload of form appointment is also shown.

The only issue I'm facing is that is does not show the appointment right after creation, even I'm calling a Reload function and also refresh storage and scheduler control

```
Private Sub SchedulerControl2_EditAppointmentFormShowing(sender As Object, e As AppointmentFormEventArgs) Handles SchedulerControl2.EditAppointmentFormShowing
        e.Handled = True
        Dim editAppointment As EditAppointment
        editAppointment = New EditAppointment(e.Appointment)
        editAppointment.ShowDialog()

        //i also tried a thread.sleep command here but it is not working

        //reloading scheduler data
        LoadAllAppointments()

        //refreshing control
        SchedulerDataStorage2.RefreshData()
        SchedulerControl2.Refresh()
        SchedulerControl2.RefreshData()
    End Sub
```

I think I've to call the `LoadAllAppointments()` in some event like `AppointmentFormShowing_Closing` but there is no such form available

Comment: Put break point after ShowDialog and see if e.Appointment has the edit changes.

Comment: on creating a new appointment `e.Appointment` only takes the date and time, did you mean that after `editAppointment.ShowDialog()` statement `e.appointment` should have all the values of appointment?

Comment: How are edits being returned?  The only way I see of edits being return is in the e.appointment.

Comment: `EditAppointment` is a custom form, I `INSERT` and `UPDATE` database on this form. After form is closed. I remove all the appointments and fetch new one from database in `LoadAllAppointments()` function. On fetching data in `LoadAllAppointments()` function new appointment row is also fetched, but it do not get updated on form, I have to reload the form to view updated

Comment: When I debug code everything runs fine. So I increased the thread timing to 3000 and now its working fine with a delay. I think the issue is due to the database. I am using ACCESS database. May be it is slow

Comment: You have : New EditAppointment(e.Appointment).  "e" gets passed in the parameter list.  The ShowDialog() should call the form load method and fill the controls on the form with the data from e.Appointment.

Comment: You cannot call the method EditAppointmentFormShowing until the database return a value.

Comment: EditAppointmentFormShowing is en event which is called whenever you try to create a new appointment or edit an appointment on XtraScheduler Control.

Comment: Yes but the event is passed an appointment in e.Appointment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do your data updates/inserts in the SchedulerControl2_EditAppointmentFormShowing rather than in the editform?  Then you can just directly add the appointment to the schedule datasource and save a round trip to the DB to fetch all appointments?